# meteor mobile configuration for windowSoftInputMode

Tags: meteor, config

I added this line
    App.setPreference('android-windowSoftInputMode', 'adjustNothing', 'android');
but it doesn't reflect at all

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Tried with also fullscreen as false as someones recommend (but didn't work to me).

Comment: Also you can remove the 'android'